# creating a list using shared_ptr and new operator

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, heap-memory

I am trying to write a code that takes an array of data in template format, makes a linked-list and returns a shared_ptr to the head of the list. here is my code, and following that is the compiler error message:

```
template <typename T> 
struct node_t{
     T data; 
     shared_ptr<node<T>> next;  
}
template <typename T> 
shared_ptr<node_t<T>> make_list(T data[], int size){
      shared_ptr<node_t<T>> head = nullptr, tail = nullptr;  
      for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
          head? tail = (new node_t<T>): head = (new node_t<T>); 
          tail = tail->next;  
      }
      tail->next = nullptr; 
      return head;  
}
```

and the compiler error is:

```
error: no match for 'operator=' in 'head = (operator new(12u),   
(<statement>, ((node_t<int>*)<anonymous>)))'
```

what is the solution here? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Don't be too clever. Use `if` statements.

Comment: It isn't at-all-clear what types `head` and `tail` in your code are. It needs updating. Knowing the how when, and when-NOT to use ternary operators would be a bonus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May I suggest you use `std::list` from the C++ standard library instead?

```
template <typename InputIt>
auto make_list(InputIt first, InputIt last) {
    return std::list<typename std::iterator_traits<InputIt>::value_type>{first, last};
}
```

Usage:

```
int arr[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
auto list = make_list(std::begin(arr), std::end(arr));
auto head = std::begin(list);
```

If you want to roll your own implementation for learning purposes then there's a number of problems with your current code.

- The assignment operator of [`std::shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) takes another `std::shared_ptr` for argument. You can't replace the internal pointer by assigning with a raw pointer (the parentheses actually make it an *expression*), instead use member function [`std::shared_ptr::reset`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/reset). This is probably the reason for the first error you describe.
- You never assign the actual data to the `data` member in the `node_t` object?
- You don't connect the elements. Where do you assign a consecutive element to `head->next`?
- It is basically an unfinished implementation that needs more logic to work.

Comment: Thank you, looks like reset will take care of the issue. of course, list would be a much better way of doing this, but I just wanted to get comfortable with shared_ptr and writing my own code for instructional purposes!

Answer (score 0):

Snps had a good answer. I also found using make_shared can convert the raw ptr to shared ptr, as follows:

```
tail = make_shared<node_t<T>>();
```